Tried mounting a tv and stud caused drywall to bow
So my house was built in 2023 using wood studs. Tried mounting a tv I’ve mounted a 1000 times in previous homes and found that as I was drilling the nail into the stud the stud started to push the drywall forward. Any thoughts/recommendations?

Need far more info on this one.  As you have it stated, the situation is impossible.

Are you mounting to an outside wall that is block by any chance?

Did you hit wood or metal?  were you expecting wood?

how do you drill a nail into the stud?

You probably hit an area where they didn't fasten the drywall properly to the stud so the drywall pulled away a bit. Another possibility is you hit a nail plate and the drywall pulled away. If you're going to continue to move, put the TV on  cabinet :-))
